# How to put a setTimeout() on map resize

Tags: openlayers, openlayers-3

I'm using an ImageWMS layer with ratio: 1.0, so my map requests are exactly the dimensions of the map `<div>`. If the user resizes the map slowly there can be dozens of map requests. I'd like to put a setTimeout() on the resize event to delay the map requests and hopefully reduce the number of requests. Any suggestions as to how I might do that?

Answer (score 2):

I ended up with the following, which delays updating the map's size (and thus making a request to the server) by half a second.

```
window.addEventListener('resize', function(e) {
    if (e) {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation()
        clearTimeout(window.updateSizeTimer)
        window.updateSizeTimer = setTimeout(function() {
          map.updateSize();
      }, 500);
    }
});
```

The event listener needs to be registered *before* creating the map object, otherwise `stopImmediatePropagation()` won't prevent the default OpenLayers resize handler from being invoked. `window.updateSizeTimer` can be any global variable, but it has to be persistent if it's to be cleared by `clearTimeout()`

Comment: I know this is an old question, but this is called debouncing/throttling (they’re not quite the same but very similar). There are libraries that can do this for you, e.g. lodash. But basically you figured out the exact solution on your own